# Entity Framework count child entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Entity Framework query that looks like this:

```
public object GetMatchupByVideoId(int id)
{
    var videoMatchup = _DBContext.Videos
        .Where(v => v.VideoID == id)
        .Select(v => new {
            id = v.MatchupID,
            players = v.Matchup.Players.Select(mp => new
            {
                character = new {
                    name = mp.Character.Name,
                    votes = v.Matchup.MatchupVotes
                        .Where(mv => mv.CharacterID == mp.CharacterID)
                },
                outcome = mp.Outcome
            })
        });

    return videoMatchup;
}
```

This query essentially gives me a matchup of characters with their respective votes.  If you look at the `votes` property, you will see it's merely filtering out the votes based on the `CharacterID`.  This works as I expect it to.

However, I want to take this a step further and actually get the count of votes for each character.  So, if I change my query to something like this:

```
public object GetMatchupByVideoId(int id)
{
    var videoMatchup = _DBContext.Videos
        .Where(v => v.VideoID == id)
        .Select(v => new {
            id = v.MatchupID,
            players = v.Matchup.Players.Select(mp => new
            {
                character = new {
                    name = mp.Character.Name,
                    votes = v.Matchup.MatchupVotes
                        .Where(mv => mv.CharacterID == mp.CharacterID)
                        .Count()
                },
                outcome = mp.Outcome
            })
        });

    return videoMatchup;
}
```

Adding a `.Count()` at the end of the query in `votes`, I get an error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/videos/1/matchup application/json 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method Mindgame.Controllers.VideosController.GetMatchupByVideoId (mindgame-api) with arguments (1) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL0OILHK80GT": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: v.Matchup.MatchupID'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultFilterAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAllResultFiltersAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResourceFilterAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 787.4541ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The point of interest in this error message is here:

```
SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: v.Matchup.MatchupID'.
```

I am unsure why I get this error if the previous query worked without the `.Count()`.  Further, I am not using `v.Matchup.MatchupID` at all in my query.  I can only imagine this is something the underlying SQL is doing.

Here are my models for `Video`, `Player`, 'Matchup`, and`MatchupVote`:

```
public class Video
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("Game")]
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("Matchup")]
    public int MatchupID { get; set; }
    public Matchup Matchup { get; set; }
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string YoutubeID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public int CharacterID { get; set; }
    public Character Character { get; set; }
    public Players.Outcomes Outcome { get; set; }
}

public class Matchup
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
    [Required]
    public int MatchupID { get; set; }
    public List<MatchupVote> MatchupVotes { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class MatchupVote
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("id")]
    public int MatchupVoteID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("Character")]
    public int CharacterID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKeyAttribute("Matchup")]
    public int MatchupID { get; set; }
    public Matchup Matchup { get; set; }
}
```

So, my question is, how can I use the `.Count()` method like this to get a count of the votes I want for each character in my query?

I am using .NET Core and Entity Framework Core for this project.

Comment: Your table  structure? Video class and player class! Update the post with it

Comment: @Aravind I updated.

Comment: Here you're referring to a foreign key in game class and user class so. Check if you configured the reverse navigation property in those two classes. If possible update them

Comment: @Aravind Are you asking if I have the `Game` and `User` navigation properties setup on another model?

Comment: No. If you are using foreign key attribute to a field the corresponding table should be having a property using which it can come back to this v table.

Comment: @Aravind I guess I am not sure what you're specifically getting at.  I updated my question to have the models for `Matchup` and `MatchupVote`.

Comment: What happens when you put the filter statement into the Count method and remove the Where?...i.e. .Count(mv => mv.CharacterID == mp.CharacterID)

Comment: @Josh Same error.

Comment: What about going back to the root dbcontext and getting the count?  _DBContext.MatchupVotes.Where(mv => mv.CharacterID == mp.CharacterID).Count()

Comment: @Josh That works!  I am curious if this will effect overall performance though in the actual SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer from the comments in case anyone stumbles across this.

```
_DBContext.MatchupVotes.Where(mv => mv.CharacterID == mp.CharacterID).Count()
```

As far as performance, I don't think it will make a difference as the underlying SQL is doing a distinct count that is filtered.  I'd check the profiler if you were super concerned about performance, but since it is a filtered count, I wouldn't think there would be a performance hit versus what you were trying.